# How do I "RegisterDelegate" for an open generic in DryIOC?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, dryioc

As per documentation, I understand that this is how you register a delegate for a normal case in DryIOC:

`Container.RegisterDelegate(typeof(IMyInterface), x => return new MyClass());`

But how do you register a delegate for an open generic? How do I supply the generic type to the delegate function shown in the following code?

`Container.RegisterDelegate(typeof(IMyInterface<>), x => return new MyClass<"I need generic type here">());`

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/OpenGenerics

Comment: Apparently it does not have anything regarding register delegate. :(

Comment: Why do you need to use `Container.RegisterDelegate`?

Comment: I actually have a factory method that generates instances. I will be using that in the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot supply open-generic type to the delegate, the same way as in C# you cannot call a constructor for the open-generic type.

Answer (score 0):

Omit the type by registration.

```
container.Register(typeof(IService<>), typeof(SomeService<>));
```